# Can a parent send a signal to all child processes in the same exact time?

Tags: c, process, signals, parent-child, kill

I am trying to find out how can I send a signal to 3 child processes in the same exact fraction of a second. Can you explain to me exactly why it's either possible or not?

If it is possible, can you help me understand using some code in C with `kill()`?

Comment: The man page of `kill` says for the first argument: *If `pid` equals 0, then `sig` is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process.* You could try sending `kill(0, xyz)`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR — No

The POSIX specification for [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) gives several ways of sending a signal to multiple processes:

> If *pid* is 0, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process has permission to send a signal.
>
> If *pid* is -1, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) for which the process has permission to send that signal.
>
> If *pid* is negative, but not -1, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the absolute value of *pid*, and for which the process has permission to send a signal.

Your request is for 'all children'.  That isn't feasible if any of the children have changed the process group ID — and that is something they're at liberty to do.  Also, if any of the children have since executed a SUID program, you may well have lost permission to send them signals.

The *pid* value of `-1` is quite dangerous; I believe it would go to all processes with the same (effective) UID as the current process.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution can be to put all children in same process group and send signal to that process group.

**example code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t got_signal;

void handler(int sig)
{
        printf("caught signal: %d\n", getpid());
        got_signal = 1;
}

int main() {

        pid_t child;
        pid_t children[3];
        int status;
        int i = 0;

        signal(SIGINT, handler);

        for (; i < 3; i++) {
                switch (child = fork()) {
                        case -1:
                                perror("could not create child: ");
                                break;
                        case 0:
                                printf("child: %d\n", getpid());
                                while (!got_signal);
                                _exit(0);
                        default:
                                children[i] = child;
                                /*put all children in process group of eldest child*/
                                setpgid(child, children[0]);
                }
        }
        sleep(1);
        /* send signal to all child by sending signal to process group of eldest child */
        kill(-children[0], SIGINT);
        waitpid(children[0], &status, 0);
        waitpid(children[1], &status, 0);
        waitpid(children[2], &status, 0);
        exit(0);
}

gcc x.c 
./a.out
child: 1893
child: 1894
child: 1895
caught signal: 1895
caught signal: 1894
caught signal: 1893
```

But as @Jonathna told it isn't feasible if any of the children have changed the process group ID — and that is something they're at liberty to do.Also, if any of the children have since executed a SUID program, you may well have lost permission to send them signals.

Hope this will help you.